# the wp_post_update isn't working all the time

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters, wp-admin, actions

When the user clicks on the preview I want to change the status of the post to "published" if not published and then reset my cache in my landing. Then after that, I want to revert the post status to the same stage.
The last part of reverting to the same stage isn't working
here is the code

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', function ( $link, \WP_Post $post )
{
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    $status_old = get_post_status($post->ID);
    if($status_old != "publish"){
//      return "http://landing.hiver.space/".$status_old;
        $post = array('ID'=>$post->ID, 'post_status' => "publish" );
        wp_update_post($post, true);
        $response = wp_remote_request("https://mywebsite.com/reset");
        $post = array('ID'=>$post->ID, 'post_status' => $status_old );
//      $post = array('ID'=>$post->ID, 'post_status' => "draft" );
        wp_update_post($post, true);
    } else {
        $response = wp_remote_request("https://mywebsite.com/reset");
    }
    return "mywebsite.com/".$slug;

 }, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That filter gets the link that the preview button has, it isn't ran when the preview button is clicked. What you've tried to do would publish any post that isn't already published as soon as you open the edit screen. What's the problem that you're trying to solve by doing this? ( and why didn't you ask about that? )

Comment: @TomJNowell I have a blog frontend in laravel, and have WordPress as the backend. 
When the user clicks on the preview button, and the post is not in published status then the status changes to "published" and makes a URL call to reset the cache in my laravel setup. After the call the status of the post changes back to what it was from "published."